# multicast traffic fails with virtualbox host only network

Tags: linux, virtualbox, multicast

I have an application where it sends some multicast request to the multicast group ,
 If I test my Client and Server application on two separate PC which are in same subnet it works fine .

Since I can not run always on two PCs  during testing of my application, I thought of using the virtualbox to run the another OS to run my server application .

My Host is ubuntu , I installed the vitrtualbox to run the another guest os linux , and since my traffic only has to be with in the HOST and Guest , I have selected a "host only network  type" .

My guest OS get the IP address but when I run my server application, It fails to join to the multicast group says

```
    "No Such Device" .
```

Can someone help me to set up a network between the Guest and HOST OS ..

My main goal is to send a multicast request and it should reach the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

In VM:

- ls /sys/class/net - get net devices. (lo, eth0, eth1...). You should have one lo and two eth devices.
- sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces. At eth0 there is a NAT connection. Lo is a localhost. We should set the Host-Only connection. Add the following:

> ```
> # The host-only network interface
> auto eth1
> iface eth1 inet static
> address 192.168.56.101 
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> network 192.168.56.0
> broadcast 192.168.56.255
> ```

(Address is taken from ipconfig/ifconfig output in host system. Instead eth1 you can have another connection name, taken from the step 4.b.i)

- For checking the edited file, run:

> ```
> sudo service network-manager restart
> ```

- Check if you have all three connections running. Check Host-Only addresses.

> ```
> ifconfig
> ```

- Reboot

> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```